# Character limit on ens subdomains

Tags: ethereum

Can anyone advise the character limits on ens sub domains? I a looking to know a min and max character limit (ens .eth addresses for example have to be at least 3 characters).

Am I able to have 1.domain.eth where I own domain.eth for example?

I've searched and am unable to find an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently for subnames, the min is one character and there is no max. It is handled by turning the label into a hash and then combining that hash with it's parent name's hash.

For the upcoming Namewrapper contract subnames will have a maximum of 255 bytes.

Comment: Thanks thats super informative. You got any link to details of the namewrapper contract? Will it replace the existing one - are no more names longer than 255 bytes going to be possible?